# Простейшее AJAX-приложение

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, javascript, google-app-engine

Допустим, у нас есть простейше приложение, которое получает через простую форму число, считает его факториал:

```
class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def fact(self, n):
        if n == 1: return 1
        else: return n * fact(n-1)

    def get(self):
        self.render("fact.html")#render - вспомогательная функция

    def post(self):
        n = self.request.get("number-input")
        res = self.fact(n)
        self.out.write(n)
```

Как добавить ко всему этому многообразию AJAX, чтобы ответ отображался на странице без перезагрузки? В файле form.html нет ничего, кроме обязательных тегов <html>, <body> etc, формы с методом post, текстового ввода и кнопки подтверждения.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="/static/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="testform">
        <input type="text" name="number-input"/>
        <input type="submit" value="fact">

    </form>
    <div class="result"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Вот так выглядит файл.html.

```
$(function () {
    var $form = $("#testform");
    $form.on("submit", function() {
        $.post('/factoreal', {
            number: $form.find('[name=number-input]').val()
            }, function(response){
                $(".result").html(response);
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

вот скрипт, который лежит вместе с библиотекой jQuery в папке static.

Comment: подключите script.js после jquery

Comment: как глупо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
    // Дожидаемся когда будет готов DOM
    $(function() {
        // Помещаем в переменную jQuery обьект с формой (найденой по id)
        var $form = $('#form');
        // Навешиваем на форму обработчика события submit
        $form.on('submit', function() {
            // Делаем POST запрос средствами jQuery
            $.post('/you/ajax/url/', {
                // массив параметров, которые хотим передать в POST
                number: $form.find('[name=number]').val() // Значение инпута, найденного в форме по атрибуту name
            }, function(response) {
                // Если сервер ответит со статусом 200 то выполнится эта функция
                // и в переменной response придет ответ сервера. Если сервер ответит
                // с content-type  'text/plain' то в переменной будет ответ одной
                // строкой, если с 'application/json' то получите свой JSON сразу в
                // виде массива javascript

                // Показываем результат в div с классом result
                $('.result').html(response); 
            });
            // Запрещаем браузеру делать то что он сам хочет делает при сабмите формы.
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="number" />
    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
<div class="result">-</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ!
Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Всё заработало так, как надо, спасибо! Вот только попытка вынести скрипт в соседний файл не удалась.

Comment: откройте консоль в chrome или firefox и смотрите на что оно ругается. Там можно довольно точно отследить проблему

Comment: Консоль ни на что не ругается. Internal Server Error.

Comment: Ну значит проблема не на клиенте

Comment: В общем-то всё равно изобилия скриптов на стороне клиента не планируется.

Answer (score 0):

jq + .post method + .load method

Comment: Я забыл уточнить, что знания JavaScript у меня поверхностные, а jquery почти нет совсем, поэтому можно поподробнее?